# Is blood orange zest different from orange zest when the fruit has not reddened?

Tags: smell, oranges, peel

I've been buying blood oranges by the kilo net, and there are always some fruits without red peel and flesh. I do feel those smell less different from ordinary oranges than the reddened specimens do, but am finding it hard to be sure I'm not imagining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Blood oranges and navel oranges are indeed different](https://uscitrus.com/blogs/citrus-delight-blog/navel-vs-blood-orange-fruit-what-are-the-differences), regardless of their color. Their aroma and flavor (zest or fruit) is certainly noticeable to me, though I suspect there is variance depending on variety of blood orange (Morro is commonly grown in Florida, USA, but there are several varieties). I think the aroma variance has less to do with color (though ripeness may impact this), than variety.  Whether or not that matters all that much in a culinary application is up to you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

There's always some variation in the blood orange skin pigmentation.

it's just more visible on blood oranges compared to "normal" oranges.

Comment: Blood oranges also taste different. Did you mean to imply anything about aroma, in particular of the zest?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.